# Lightning web component listen to Aura Events

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a Lightning Record Page which uses multiple components, some are LWC, some are Aura components.
I am trying to figure out a way to make sure they all refresh nicely.
For the Aura components, I use the standard `$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();`
For the LWCs, I am using `fireEvent(this.pageRef, 'refresh', this.name);` imported from the pubsub component, which is available in the LWC recipies found [Here](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes)

My question is this, how do I add an event listener to the LWC which is listening for an Aura event (specifically force:refreshView) to ensure that LWC logic can be executed when events are dispatched from aura components.
I have tried the following:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.addEventListener('force:refreshView', this.handleRefresh.bind(this));
  }
handleRefresh() {
   //do some stuff        
}
```

and I have also tried this:

```
 connectedCallback() {
    registerListener('force:refreshView', this.handleRefresh, this);       
}
```

There has to be a way for a lighting web component to know when an aura event is fired...

Edit: this question is not a duplicate of [This Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/251299/force-refresh-view-in-lwc). The other question is asking about how to call the refresh from a Lightning Web Component, my question is how do we listen for events dispatched from Aura components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, it requires what I've coined as `brokering`. It requires an Aura wrapper to handle (i.e. register the event listener) and then deal with `brokering` it down to an embedded child-LWC which is itself pub-subbed to the LWCs you wish to broker to.

In short, it's complicated, rough, and not ideal. But, if you have a lot of aura components you may need to do it.

I have covered this in a somewhat related (LWC to Aura) [answer here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/256656/718) but the design pattern is the same for (Aura to LWC) since you just pubsub the other way.

Just to be clear, I am currently doing this in production right now, this is not theoretical:

**MessageBrokerAura.cmp**

```xml
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHomeforce:hasRecordId">
  <aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="{! c.handleForceRefreshViewForLWC }"/>
  <c:messageBrokerLWC aura:id="messageBroker"></c:messageBrokerLWC>
</aura:component>
```

**MessageBrokerAuraController.js**

```js
handleForceRefreshViewForLWC: function(component, event, helper) {
  component.find("messageBroker").forceRefreshInitiated();
},
```

**messageBrokerLWC.js**

```js
@api
forceRefreshInitiated() {
  fireEvent(this.pageRef, 'forceRefresh'); // your LWCs pubsub to this channel
}
```

Comment: thanks tsalb! this was exactly what I am looking for :)

Comment: `fireEvent(this.pageRef, 'forceRefresh');` --- what is `fireEvent`.Is this a inbuilt already defined property or a custom one?

Comment: @devforce it's the lwc-recipes repo [pubsub](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/3036d3f3e3eed938fb70850c38c96b9c0f401fe7/force-app/main/default/lwc/pubsub/pubsub.js#L96) mechanism

Comment: Thanks @tsalb. I got it now

Answer (score 0):

> my question is how do we listen for events dispatched from Aura components.

I don't think you can directly do this because of the difference in the Events as in Lightning Aura Components (LAC) vs. (DOM) Events in LWC. You could do it other way round, i.e., fire an event from LWC to a wrapped Aura Component as in [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/251299/force-refresh-view-in-lwc).

However, one of the approaches here though is what I think you can utilize  is by using [`aura:if`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:if/documentation) within your component (*disclaimer: I haven't tested it out myself, but seems this should work*).

The idea is that whenever you fire an event from a LAC, utilize an attribute on the LAC so that you re-render the LWC and pass respective values out there to the LWC. The time you re-render the LWC, the attribute in the LWC then captures the updated values baed on events passed from the LAC and you can then take further action based on it in your LWC.

Something as below, where `name` is a public attribute within your LWC and that `refreshValue` is the value that's changed in the LAC.

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showHide}">
        <c:myLWCComponent name="{!v.eventValue}" />
    </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

And you set the value of eventValue`in the JS Controller of your LAC and`showHide`from`true`-->`false`and then`true` so that you can force the LWC to be re-rendered as well as pass the updated value from LAC.

Comment: Check out my updated answer. It's possible to provide inter-operability using a brokering system, I put up an example (this is an abstraction of what's running in my spring 19 production).