# imperative apex method not called from wire

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a scenario, wherein I display a Warning message using toast when the record is updated to meet certain criteria. I am trying to use a combination of @wire and imperative apex.

Below is the code snippet:

```
@api recordId;
    bShowToast = false;
    error;
    @wire (getRecord, {recordId : '$recordId' ,fields: [ 'Claim__c.StartDate__c']})
    getClaimRecord({error , data}){
        if(data){
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
            console.log('data : ' ,data);  
        }else if(error){
            this.error = error;
        }
        this.showToast();
    }
showToast() {
        verifyEndDate({sClaimId: this.recordId}) //imperative apex call
        .then(result =>{
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
            console.log('result : ' ,result);
            this.bShowToast = result;
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
            console.log('bShowToast : ' ,this.bShowToast);
            if(this.bShowToast){
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Get Help',
                        message: 'ACTION REQUIRED...',
                })
                );
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
            console.log('Error Occured : ' ,error);
        });
    }
```

I send the value from apex method to display toast based on certain values on the record (majorly depend on changes to a single field).

Now, the problem is that it retains the value from very first apex call and the value doesn't change even if the back-end method is supposed to send other value. 
Eg: if on page/component load - the method returns **true**, it'll display same value even if I update the record to make the value as **false**. 
I tried using refreshApex() but that didn't work for me.

Any idea how this can be achieved.

When trying to use Aura component to force refresh.. I can't even find the aura component on custom component list. I have no experience with aura and directly started with LWC.. 
Below is the code for aura components:

```
<aura:component >
    <c:claimWarningMessage onrecordChange="{!c.refreshView}" ></c:claimWarningMessage>
</aura:component>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
({
    refreshView: function(component, event) {
    // refresh the view
    $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
    }
})
```

I added below line in showToast() method...

> this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('recordChange'));

Any idea why I'm not able to see the component in custom component list?

Comment: You are updating that value on UI or in backend by some other process?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal  I'm updating it on record page itself where the component is placed.

Comment: verifyEndDate only contains recordId are you also sending the updated value of record?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal I'm only sending the recordId and the apex method queries the record using the id. Ideally, apex method should be able to retrieve the updated record and send back the appropriate value but that's not happening at all.

Comment: So, there is another component, page that updates the value of record, but the your lwc component still shows the old value?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal No No.. The component actually resides on the record page and all I'm trying to do is display a warning message on the record page using toast when a specific condition is met on edit of record(condition is being evaluated in apex method - so I'm just passing the id).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101245/discussion-between-pranay-jaiswal-and-ashutosh-arora).

Answer (score 0):

You are using standard record SF save. The record Save will fire `refreshView` event. Unfortunately, lwc cant listen to refresh view event natively and react to it. You have to use an aura wrapper around it.

c:customWrapper.html

```
<aura:component>

<aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="{! c.refreshLWC}" />
<c:customLWCComponent aura:id="myLWCCompnent"></c:customLWCComponent>
</aura:component>
```

Aura Controller:

```
refreshLWC: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.find("myLWCCompnent").refresh();
    },
```

Then in your lwc:

```
 @track backupObjClaim;
 getClaimRecord(result){
        this.backupObjClaim= result;

}


@api 
    refresh(){//this method is called from aura
        return refreshApex(this.backupObjClaim);
    }
```

src: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/257396/19118

Comment: I tried doing something similar but it doesn't work.. I'm not able to see the aura component in list of custom components.. I have updated the question.. please scroll down to bottom

Comment: You have to create one of your own. That will contain your lwc

Comment: that's exactly what I did..

Comment: Why are you firing `$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();`, you have to listen to this event.